# Separation of concerns in JSF Beans?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Im currently using JSF2, and i notice the JSF bean could have a lot of responsibility, and if combined will look like lots of codes. These include :

1. holding the state / data
2. could be a backing bean for the UI component
3. action methods definition
4. action listener methods definition
5. navigation
6. calling the services
7. all the setter n getters

Does it make anysense to break these into several classes or do you usually combine all of them together ?

Currenly for every JSF Bean, i define another class to hold the view data / state along with the setter getters.

How do you usually do it ? Please share your experience !

Thank you =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every property which is been used in action(listener) methods needs to stay in the backing bean. The remnant most likely belongs in its own class which can in turn be a different (managed/entity)bean, eventually as a (managed)property of the bean where it originated.